# Asynchronous node.js calls fail in when run in a VM script

Tags: ajax, node.js, virtual-machine, child-process

I've managed to write an extension to my custom **node.js** server, that allows an AJAX script to be run using the **VM module**. I've also succeeded in persuading VM to acknowledge the existence of **require**, which is necessary for my scripts to be of any use.

But I've hit a truly weird and intractable problem.

When I run the AJAX script "normally", by handing it off to a child process using **child_process.spawn()**, all my asynchronous API calls work as expected, and my callback chain runs to completion. In the case of the script I'm currently testing, this uses **fs.readdir()** to launch the callback chain, and it works in child process mode, returning directory listings to the HTML client that makes the initial AJAX request.

But when I run the AJAX script inside VM using **vm.script()**, followed by **script.runInContext()**, something weird happens. The script reaches my fs.readdir() call, but the callback is never called! The entire script stalls at this point!

Since the same V8 engine is running the code in both child process and VM mode, I'm more than a little puzzled, as to why the AJAX script works perfectly if launched in child process mode, but fails to launch the callback chain at all when launched in VM mode.

The only reason I can think of, why VM doesn't like my AJAX script, is because the callbacks are defined as inner functions of a closure, and the outer function comes to an end after the fs.readdir() call. But if that's the case, why does the script work perfectly, both when run in the node.js debugger, and passed to a child process by my server after an AJAX request?

The documentation for VM makes no mention of fs calls being blocked if called within code running under VM, and I wouldn't have embarked upon this development path, if I'd been informed beforehand that such blocking had been implemented.

So what is going on?

EDIT: Here's the code that processes the arguments passed to the script. It calls a function getCmdArgs(), defined earlier, which I don't need to list here because it's been tested and works. It works in both child process mode and VM mode, and conducts a stringent test to see if the argument passing variables needed to supply the script with its data actually exist, before
returning a suitable return argument (the args in question if they exist). Once again, this part works.

```
//Get the arguments passed to the script - new dual mode version! See function notes above.
var args = getCmdArgs();

//Check to see if the script is being run in a VM sandbox by the server ...
if (args[0] == "RunInVM")

        runMode = "V";

else

        runMode = "P";

//End if/else
```

Next, once the script arguments have been passed to the script, it's time to process them, and find out what directory is being referenced. I use an anonymised path reference, which begins with the word "root", the idea being that the client does not need to know where on the server it has had its permitted storage allocated, only that it has storage on disc that it's permitted to access. The client, once given this, can manipulate that directory tree at will, and the child process versions of the scripts that permit this all work. So, this is how the arguments are processed:

```
//Set our root directory, to which all other directory references will be attached ...
//ROOTPATH is set at the beginning of the script, and is known only to the script, not the client

var dirRoot = ROOTPATH;

//Now get the arguments that were passed to the script ...

var tmpChk = args[2];
var queryMarker = tmpChk.indexOf("?");
if (queryMarker != -1)
{
//Strip off the initial "?"

        var actualQuery = tmpChk.substring(queryMarker+1);

//Separate the x=y parts from each other
        var queryParts = actualQuery.split("=");
        var argType = queryParts[0];
        var argData = queryParts[1];

        if (argType === "dir")
        {

                requestedDir = argData;

//Here, we have an argument of the form "dir=xxx". Find out what "xxx" is.

                if (argData === "root")
                        dirName = dirRoot;
                else
                {

//Here, we have an argument of the form "dir=root/xxx". Find out what "xxx" is, and make it a subdirectory of our
//chosen root directory.

                        var subIndex = argData.indexOf("root/");
                        var subDir = argData.substring(subIndex+5);

                        subDir = subDir.replace(/\x2F/g, path.sep);

                        subDir = qs.unescape(subDir);

                        dirName = dirRoot+path.sep+subDir;

//Also, insert an entry for the parent directory into our custom DirEntry array ...

                        var newEntry = new DirEntry();
                        newEntry.fileName = "(Parent Directory)";
                        newEntry.fileType = "DIR";
//Remember we're using the UNIX separator for our GET call!
                        var pdIdx = requestedDir.lastIndexOf("/");
                        var pd = requestedDir.substring(0,pdIdx);
//This is the secure path to the parent directory
                        newEntry.filePath = pd;
                        myDirEntries[idx2++] = newEntry;

                //End if/else
                }

        //End if
        }
}
```

The above generates the initial directory entry to be returned (via a custom DirEntry() object), and again, this all works. It also determines what path is to be referenced when searching the server's storage.

At this point, we're ready to roll, and we call fs.readdir() accordingly:

```
//Get entire contents of dir in one go!
fs.readdir(dirName, DirContentsCallback);
```

Now when running in child process mode, the above function executes, and the callback function DirContentsCallBack(), which is the first part of the callback chain, is duly launched. But when I try to run it in VM mode, this doesn't happen. The callback is *never called*. Now if fs.readdir() had actually executed, and an error had been generated, then surely my callback would have been called, with an error argument that was non-null? Instead, the whole script just grinds to a halt and hangs.

I inserted a series of console.log() calls to check the progress of the script, to see if any parts of the callback chain were ever executed, and NONE of the console.log() calls fired. My entire callback chain stalled. This does not happen if I run the script in child process mode, by passing it to cp.spawn() - instead, I end up with a completed AJAX transaction, and my directory contents are nicely displayed in the client, once the client receives the JSON data generated by the script. What's even more bizarre, is that the SAME DATA is being passed to the script in both modes - I've checked this repeatedly. Yet the data that worked perfectly in child process mode, and generates a target directory path that is duly examined for entries, comes crashing to a silent halt, the moment I try executing fs.readdir() in VM mode.

No to be perfectly honest, I don't see why I needed to bother posting a host of prior code that all works, when the part that DOESN'T work in VM mode is the last line of the lot. What I opened this question with, seemed to me perfectly sufficient to alert people to the problem. But if it means I receive meaningful answers, then so be it - waste time posting code that works I shall.

Comment: The problem is on line 27 of lib/main.js. All kidding aside, you should post the relevant code for us to help you.

Comment: Quite simply, the script takes the following format:

function closure()
{

Comment: I just tried. "Message too long by 58 characters", and that was with a highly truncated code snippet. Somehow don't think 500 lines of script is going to fit in here ... plus I was stopped from editing my broken comment above. Looks like I'm in for a /lot/ of frustration here ...

Comment: @DavidEdwards add the script (preferably an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: Code added. Though I'm still wholly unconvinced that it was necessary, for reasons stated in the edit.